# How do I mix formats in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I've got a string like

```
 ="Daily Avg: " &AVERAGE(C3:C13)
```

I'd like to be able to apply number formats within my cell's formula. Is this possible without custom scripts?

I've searched Google's help centre but found nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The text() function might help you out. There is better documentation of it on the Excel help site: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx

What you're looking for is wrapping your `average()` function in the `text()` function like this:

```
="Daily Avg: " &text(AVERAGE(C3:C13),"0.00")
```

`text()` works like this:

`text(number,format)` where `number` refers to the data you're trying to convert and `format` refers to the way you'd like numbers to be displayed. In my example I just carried out the decimal to 2 places.

Answer (score 3):

The way you prepare the notation, makes me think of how I do it in MS Access.

In a Google spreadsheet you can also use the following straight forward formula:

```
=CONCAT("Daily Avg: ";FIXED(AVERAGE(C3:C13);2))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to add a string with a variable or function then more string, here is the format:

```
="Text " &DATEDIF(DATE(2015,9,8), TODAY(), "D" )  &" text."
```

**Notice** that adding more components requires the `&`.